# A portable Git download is supposed to be a 7z.exe?

Tags: git, 7zip

Probably a stupid/paranoid question, but I don't see a way do a checksum, so I have to ask... should this 7z Git file have an exe extension?  It reminds me of one of those stupid malicious download tricks which hopes that the user has "hide known file extensions" enabled (since Microsoft stupidly has that a default option).

PortableGit-2.10.1-64-bit.7z.exe

From https://git-scm.com/download/win

Is this just a self extracting 7z or was the dang site hacked? And why no checksum?

Comment: So, why downvote this? If it's not on-topic enough, let's delete it. I can't delete because it was answered!

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly be the answer you are looking for, but here is a work around to verify the contents of the file without executing it.

Self executable archives usually can be opened and extracted using the compression program which created it. So if this a real 7z self extracting archive,then it should be openable using the official 7zFM program. You can download and install that program from the official source and use it to open or extract the file in question without executing it.

Comment: Since apparently this is deemed a "bad" question, could you delete this answer so (maybe) I can delete the question?